# Grapejs together Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, grapesjs

I'm using Grapejs with Vue and so far it seems to work fine, I'm having a problem with the "grapesjs-preset-webpage" library.

I am not able to add more HTML options, such as "Columns", "Videos" and other settings that at least appear when using the CDN.

My question would be how do I add more blocks beyond the 3 that already come as default?
(link-block, qyote, text-basic).

My configuration file is like this:

```
<script>
  import grapesjs from 'grapesjs'
  import 'grapesjs/dist/css/grapes.min.css'
  import 'grapesjs/dist/grapes.min.js'
  import plugin from 'grapesjs-preset-webpage';

  export default {
   name: 'BuilderHtml',
  
   mounted(){
     grapesjs.init({
       container: '#gjs',
       height: '900px',
       width: '100%',
       plugins: [plugin],        
       storageManager: {
         id: 'gjs-',
         type: 'local',
         autosave: true,
         storeComponents: true,
         storeStyles: true,
         storeHtml: true,
         storeCss: true,
       },
       deviceManager: {
         devices:
         [
           {
             id: 'desktop',
             name: 'Desktop',
             width: '',
           },
           {
             id: 'tablet',
             name: 'Tablet',
             width: '768px',
             widthMedia: '992px',
           },
           {
             id: 'mobilePortrait',
             name: 'Mobile portrait',
             width: '320px',
             widthMedia: '575px',
           },
         ]
       },
       pluginsOpts: {
         [plugin]: {
            blocksBasicOpts: {
                blocks: ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column3-7', 'text', 'link', 'image', 'video'],
                flexGrid: 1,
           },          
           blocks: ['link-block', 'quote', 'text-basic', 'column3'],
         },
       }
     })
   }
  }
  </script>
```

I'm trying to add this configuration below, but no new block is appearing, did I do something wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add new blocks, you can use the `grapesjs-blocks-basic` plugin or initialise custom blocks.

```
import grapesjsblocks from 'grapesjs-blocks-basic'

plugins: [grapesjsblocks],
  pluginsOpts: {
    "gjs-blocks-basic": {},
  }
```